# How change which php.ini symfony does use ?

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, pdo

I'm in in pain using symfony 2 because it's currently using my native's macOS php while i'm running it on my server WEB.
I'd like SF2 to use php.ini from my MAMP with php 7 and its extension pdo_pgsql to connect to my postgreSQL database.
Actually, SF2 uses my /usr/php.ini file which is an old version of PHP doens't include pgsql extension ...

When I run /web/phpinfo it tells me it's running on php 7 but a php --ini on console + php -v tells me 5.5.30 is used, located in /etc/php.ini when phpinfo(); AND web/config.php tells me to edit my /Application/MAMP/.../php.ini (running on php7).

Why is my project using my native's OS PHP ? Thanks a lot

Comment: Not a big Mac user but adjust your PATH to point to your php7 executable and should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

MAMP usually runs on port 8080 while your "native" apache is probably running on port 80 (which is used by default in your browser). Try accessing your project via

```
http://localhost:8080/app_dev.php
```

Comment: MAMP is using 8888 port, i already made a vhost to my symfony's project which works. That's why my phpinfo(); (of my sf2 project) tells me it's running on 7.0. I just don't understand why SF2 can't use a proper php.ini i'm just stuck here for 2 days now :( Thanks for response

Comment: How do you run your `/web/phpinfo` ? Is your vhost configured for MAMP or Apache? What happens when your run `http://localhost:8888/app_dev.php` ?

Comment: For MAMP. I created a phpinfo.php on my SF2 project. (sfproject.local:8888/web/phpinfo.php). It happens nothing when I run http://localhost:8888/app_dev.php because i'm using a vhost. Using sfproject.local:8888/app_dev.php just send me to my homepage ... (It works well but my problem isn't here). I just can't connect to my postgreSQL database because of driver which's not found in /etc/php.ini (which is normal because i do not want SF2 to use this file !)

Comment: Thanks for responses

Comment: When you run `sfproject.local:8888/phpinfo.php` it tells you that php7 is used and that pdo_pqsql is installed? What does `sfproject.local:8888/config.php` says?

Comment: It says that all is ok and my configuration must be done in my /MAMP/php.ini ... There is also pgsql extension in there

Comment: sorry I have no idea what's going on